# Is there a way to show the index of atoms in rdkit.Chem.rdmolops.GetAdjacencyMatrix?

Tags: rdkit, cheminformatics

I'm trying to convert a compound from mol to adjacency matrix. However, i encountered a problem that rdkit.Chem.rdmolops.GetAdjacencyMatrix() doesn't provide the index of the atoms for the adjacency matrix. Is there any way to include the index data for the adjacency matrix in rdkit?

rdkit.Chem.rdmolops.GetAdjacencyMatrix((Mol)mol)

Answer (score 3):

As the RDKit AdjacencyMatrix is ordered from zero upwards, you can convert it to a Pandas dataframe.

```
from rdkit import Chem
import pandas as pd

s = 'CCC(C(O)C)CN'
mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(s)
```

[image: mol with numbers]

```
am = Chem.GetAdjacencyMatrix(mol)
print(am)

[[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(am)
print(df)

   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
1  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
2  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  0
3  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0
4  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
5  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
6  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1
7  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
```

If you want elements instead of indices

```
element = [atom.GetSymbol() for atom in mol.GetAtoms()]
print(element)

['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'O', 'C', 'C', 'N']

df_e = pd.DataFrame(am, index=element,  columns=element)
print(df_e)

   C  C  C  C  O  C  C  N
C  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
C  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
C  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  0
C  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0
O  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
C  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
C  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1
N  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
```

Comment: Thanks! but is there any way to know which atom each index means? In your code, for example, is there a way to know if atom number 0 is carbon with rdkit?

Comment: I have edited the answer. Just get the elements in their order.